# What is the equivalent of the jQuery function load() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am rendering a php script in my html with the jquery function load, so I want to use pure javascript now without the jquery library. Here is the code:

```
$(()=>{
    $('#loadTable').load('./php/loadTable.php');
})
```

How can I achieve this using pure javascript?

Comment: Sixth result when searching [“\[js\] load without jquery”](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+load+without+jquery) here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetch` and `Element.innerHTML`:

```
fetch('./php/loadTable.php')
  .then(resp => {
    // TODO: add error handling
    return resp.text();
  })
  .then(text => {
     document.querySelector('#loadTable').innerHTML = text;
  });
```